# How to format date to today date and example 8:00 AM or 9:00 PM ? Moment JS

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I need to convert date to any format:

today
and setTime  for 8:00 AM
Example if i want to set snack for 8:00 am

I am try but got 'Invalid Date'

```
let breakFastFormatedTime: any =  new Date();
breakFastFormatedTime =  moment().set({"hour": 8, "minute": 0}).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm A');
```

I am also try with

```
  const day = moment('2020-01-01');
  day.set({ hours: 8, minutes: 0 });
```

I but i need current new Date.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const today = new Date();
console.log(moment(today).set({
  hour: 8,
  minute: 0
}).format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm A"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question 
improves its long-term value. Consider reading [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and [edit] your answer to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [moment defaults](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/defaults/)

```js
var timeAndDate = moment({hour: 8, minute: 0});

console.log(timeAndDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: But i need here and date example YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: this is best time "2020-11-10T16:00:08.611Z"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you got your moment answer. Here is one without - Vanilla JS using [intl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat)

```js
const config = {
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric',
  hour12: true
}
const d = new Date();
d.setHours(8, 0, 0, 0)
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', config).format(d));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var currentDate = (date) => {
  // current hour and min
  var hr = date.getHours();
  var mn = date.getMinutes();

  // extract am pm 
  var ampm = hr >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
  hr = hr % 12;
  hr = hr ? hr : 12;
  mn = mn < 10 ? '0' + mn : mn;

  // concat everything as a string
  var stringTime = hr + ':' + mn + ' ' + ampm;

  return stringTime;
}

var date = new Date();

console.log(currentDate(date));
```

Comment: Please comment your answer